# How to evaluate baked physics data from python (fast)?

Tags: python, baking

I need to evaluate lots of position data for lots of objects.
The physics have been baked, so I think that there should be a fast way to access this.
I assume, I should find the baked physics as fcurves or the like? However, I would look for fcurves in an action in animation_data, but  `bpy.context.blend_data.objects['MyObject'].animation_data` is empty. After all, animation is probably the wrong place to look for to begin with ...

I tried a workaround with `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)` and `A.matrix_world.to_translation()`, but this seems to be awfully slow and unsuitable for mass evaluation looping over many frames and objects.

I suppose there should be a much faster way in the situation at hand, i.e., with baked physics - but how?

---

*In case this is an XY-problem: Ultimately, I want to find out info about all collisions in the simulation: Which object changed its momentum by which unusual (i.e., not caused by gravity/free fall) amount at which exact point in time? I'd try to answer this by finding velocities and accelerations and changes of accelerations etc and so "reverse engineering" the simulation. If this question can be tackled directly in a different way, I'd be happy to hear about it.*